# HCatalog multiple SLF4J bindings error message

Tags: hadoop, binding, hcatalog

as Im following a tutorial on hadoop (http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/) I cannot create a table using a downloaded data file as I get this error message:

HCatClient error on create table: {"statement":"use default; create table nyse_stocks(`exchange` string, `stock_symbol` string, `date` string, `stock_price_open` float, `stock_price_high` float, `stock_price_low` float, `stock_price_close` float, `stock_volume` bigint, `stock_price_adj_close` float) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t';","error":"unable to create table: nyse_stocks","exec":{"stdout":"","stderr":"SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.\nSLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-913/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]\nSLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-913/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-913-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]\nSLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.\nSLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]\n Command  was terminated due to timeout(60000ms).  See templeton.exec.timeout property","exitcode":143}} (error 500)

could someone please help me out in easy language and bear with me that I am a beginner,

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Of the 2 SLF4J bindings being listed in the warning you'll need to exclude one of them from the classpath.

Even though this is a warning SLF4J will pick one logging framework/implementation and bind with it - binding is determined by the JVM and is mostly considered a random function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but where can I get to Hbase (through HortonWorks)?